# Обязательно ли использовать this в методах, где нет конфликта между полем и параметром?

Tags: java, this

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human Vasya = new Human("Вася",20);
        Vasya.talk();
    }
}

class Human{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Human(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    void talk(){
        System.out.println(this.name); //Обязательно ли здесь использовать this?
        System.out.println(this.age);  //Обязательно ли здесь использовать this?
    }
}
```

Comment: если в текущей области видимости (блок) нет локальных переменных с таким же именем, то необязательно

Comment: Нужно использовать, чтобы понимать, что переменная используется из текущего класса, иначе `super` которая используется из родителя. Это делается, для того, чтобы другие разработчики понимали откуда происходит вызов. А еще, чтобы не перекрывать переменные аргументов и свойств класса.

Comment: @And да никто не использует эти `this`, кроме случаев, когда есть переменные с таким же именем. Обычно это конструкторы, да сеттеры

Comment: @And открой любой проект на java да посмотри. Даже сама JDK не использует в своих исходниках this.

Comment: @СергейМишин, да, тогда как же нам вызывать конструкторы одного и того-же класса в текущем классе? О загадка та да? Это уже говорит о том, что вы вовсле не открывали реальные проекты. без него не обойтись в сложных задачах.

Comment: @And в вопросе сложная задача? Нет. Конструкторы? Нет. Не надо вводить в заблуждение людей, что нужно **всегда** их использовать. Есть *особые* случаи. Но **НЕ** всегда

Comment: Коллеги, возможно вы аккумулируете свои мнения и внесёте их в поле ответ?

Comment: @СергейМишин, да это как минимум должен знать каждый, что и для чего, вы же вовсе его не будете использовать и наделаете глупостей, ибо для всех как заявили вы, оно не нужно вообще. Мол кроме 1 случая скажете вы, но тут уже как минимум в 3х, а дальше больше.

Comment: @And изначально контекст был задан в виде вопроса ТС. Мой комментарий был относительно этого самого контекста. А вот вас, Остап, понесло))) Благодарю за то, что беспокоитесь о моей персоне. Очень приятно. И да, всегда везде совать this - не нужно. Ровно так же, как писать ООП ради ООП и применять паттерны проектирования ради паттернов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование данного ключевого слова не обязательно, кроме случаев где имя аргумента равняется имени поля класса. Т. е., в конструкторе вы обязаны написать `this`, а в методе `talk` это необязательно, так как конфликта имен нет

Answer (score 0):

-- Нужно для того, чтобы можно было использовать одинаковые параметры - свойств класса и  аргументов в функции, так-как, аргументы функции будут перекрывать свойства (поля) классов - без `this.var` никак, так-как `var === var`, будет одно и тоже - связи с тем, что у методов своя область видимости, будет считаться тоже-самое.

-- Нужен, для обращения, к ранее определенным конструкторам класса.

-- Нужен, для понимания из какого класса взят параметр, `this` или же `super` (сразу понятно, откуда было или будет вызвано - из родителя или наследника).

Не придется гадать `this.prop` или  `super.prop`, искать в текущем классе не нужно, если `super.var`, уже явно указано, что родитель.

-- Если в текущей области, нет расширенной функциональности в классе, можно работать без `this` и `super`, чтобы явно иметь ввиду, что нет никаких разветвлений.